# procedimiento almacenado no retorna respuesta [mysql]

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedure, mysql-workbench

Hola a todos buenos dias, tengo que hacer una busqueda en un formulario de c#, para esto tengo un procedimiento almacenado en MYSQL que mostrara los resultados de una determinada palabra ingresada en un textbox, el tema es que el sp no retorna ningun resultado, el codigo del procedimiento es el siguiente:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`administrador`@`%` PROCEDURE `spBuscarFunNombre`(
in textoBuscar varchar(100)
)
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM funcionario WHERE nombres LIKE '% textoBuscar %' ;
END
```

Lo pruebo en la consola de `mysql` y no trae registros (probado con registros que existen en la tabla).

Estare haciendo algo mal? no me marca error el sp.

Saludos a todos y gracias

Comment: Es probable que sea por el espacio que tienes al final de tu LIKE; reemplaza '%textoBuscar %' por '%textoBuscar%'. Prueba y me cuentas.

Comment: hola, gracias por tu tiempo, tampoco resulta...

Comment: Creo que intentas que inserte tu variable textoBuscar dentro de la cadena pero no estás haciendo ninguna concatenación ni interpolación, intenta agregar los % desde antes de que llegue al procedimiento y si regresa resultados ese era el problema.

Comment: Dime, la palabra 'textoBuscar'; realmente existe información con ese nombre en tu columnas 'nombres' ??  o 'textoBuscar' es un parametro ??

Comment: como antes que llegue al procedimiento?

Comment: textoBuscar es el parametro que viene desde el formulario

Comment: Entonces la sintaxis sería asi : LIKE '%'+ textoBuscar +'%';

Comment: Si ha de ser un parámetro, debes anteponer el '@' al inicio : LIKE '%' + @textoBuscar + '%'

Comment: me arroja un error de sintaxis: missing 'semicolon' (con o sin el arroba en el parametro)

Comment: Debería poder todo el query de tu procedimiento para ver donde esta el error, el tema de LIKE ya se solucionó, ahora el error es otro y es de sintaxis de Store Procedure

Comment: CREATE DEFINER=`administrador`@`%` PROCEDURE `spBuscarFunNombre`(
in textoBuscar varchar(100)
)
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM funcionario WHERE textoBuscar LIKE '%' + @textoBuscar + '%' ;
END

Comment: Prueba poniendo $$ al final de tu END

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acá unos ejemplos del comodín LIKE:

```
SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE nombre LIKE '%m%';
```

En el código superior estamos buscando los clientes que contengan una ‘m’ en el nombre.

```
SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE nombre LIKE 'M%';
```

En el código superior estamos buscando los clientes cuyo nombre comienza por ‘M’.

```
SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE nombre LIKE '%a';
```

En el código superior estamos buscando los clientes cuyo nombre termina con ‘a’.

```
SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE nombre LIKE '_a%';
```

En el código superior estamos buscando los clientes cuyo nombre tiene como segundo caracter la ‘a’.

```
SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE nombre LIKE '_______';
```

En el código superior estamos buscando los clientes cuyo nombre tiene 7 caracteres de longitud.

```
SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE nombre LIKE '%a%' or nombre LIKE '%r%' ;
```

En el código superior estamos buscando los clientes cuyo nombre tiene una ‘a’ y una ‘r’.

[Link de Referencia](https://www.anerbarrena.com/mysql-like-5657/)

En tu caso, la palabra 'textoBuscar' es un parámetro por lo tanto tu sintaxis debería ser así :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`administrador`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spBuscarFunNombre`(in textoBuscar varchar(100))
BEGIN 
   SELECT * FROM funcionario WHERE nombres LIKE '%' + textoBuscar + '%'; 
END;
```

Comment: aun asi, me sigue marcando error en el primer '%'

Comment: ...ese primer '%' está por demás: Por favor revisa la sintaxis correcta en este [sitio web mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) He editado también la respuesta.

Comment: si estuve revisando la doc de mysql, y de hecho los ejemplo que aparecen fueron la base para la query, peor no ejecuta, no da error de sintaxis pero no trae el resultado

Comment: Prueba haciendo debug, y dime si llega algún valor a tu parámetro 'textoBuscar', si no llega nada entonces el problema es otro, y si existe un valor, pruebas el select "SELECT * FROM funcionario WHERE nombres LIKE '%' + textoBuscar + '%'" en tu IDE de BD, reemplazando el parametro por un valor. Te arroja resultados??? Me cuentas.

Comment: en workbench, pruebo el sp pasandole un valor (sin parametro) y me funciona: CREATE DEFINER=`administrador`@`%` PROCEDURE `spBuscaFunRut`(
)
BEGIN
SELECT * from funcionario WHERE nombres LIKE '%' "nico" '%';
END

Comment: debugeo y el parametro a otra consulta llega bien

Answer (score 0):

La sintaxis es la siguiente:

```
 CREATE DEFINER = 'administrador'@'%'
 PROCEDURE test.spBuscarFunNombre(in textoBuscar varchar(100) )
 BEGIN 
 SELECT * FROM funcionario WHERE nombres LIKE CONCAT('%', textoBuscar, '%');
 END
```

**Resultado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero sea de tu ayuda, saludos...

Comment: no da error, pero no muestra resultados

Comment: error de missing 'semicolon' y me marca el primer '%'

Comment: Lo edite nuevamente

Comment: TAMPOCO, no trae ningun resultado

Comment: Ahora si, prueba el nuevo SP actualizado en mi respuesta. prueba y pega tal cual ;)

Comment: ahora si funciono francisco, estabamos saltando el concat por lo que veo :) ...gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Tambien las comas, no olvides marcar con ticket la respuesta, saludos ;)